# Java - is it correct to continuously pass info to new windows?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have only just finished taking Java as a college course and have only worked on a small group class project to date, so my Java knowledge is quite limited. I am trying to develop my own Java program right now for my own needs (independent of school projects) and I am having a couple of conceptual issues.

I am working on developing a fitness program. Users will have to create accounts (which are stored locally for the time being). Once creating an account, a user can login to the system and create a Routine for them to follow. The definition of a routine is a workout program, so for example a full body workout split is a routine, whereas a chest day/back day/arm day is a separate routine. Each routine is composed of a list of workouts, and each workout is composed of a list of exercises. So to recap, taking for example a chest day/back day/arm day routine:

The routine is: Chest Day/Back Day/Arm Day

The workouts of this routine are: Chest Workouts, Back Workouts, and Arm Workouts

The exercises of the Chest Workout could be: Bench Press, Dumbbell Press, Flyes
The exercises of the Back Workout could be: Deadlifts, Lat Pulldowns, Rows
The exercises of the Arm Workout could be: Curls, Tricep Extensions, and Pulldowns

Hopefully that is enough clarification for you guys to understand the gist of what I am trying to create.

Currently, users are stored in an ArrayList of type Person (where each person has a name, password, and some health info) within my Subcontroller class. I know this isn’t the most secure way of doing so, but I am working on simplicity and trying to understand programming more before moving onto more advanced concepts.

Once the program runs, a user creates their account. Once they login to this account, as they press the “LOGIN” button, I use loops to find their username in the ArrayList, and try to match the inputted password to the password in the object found in the ArrayList. If it matches (authentication successful), then I open up a new window which I called “LoggedIn”. This window has a simple greeting label, and some buttons to create routines, view current routines, edit/add workouts and exercises.

1) Is it wrong for me to store these users in an ArrayList named “users” of type Person? What drawbacks will this lead me to in the future? Should I be storing logins in a plain text file?
2) As I am progressing deeper into the program, and creating more windows based off user clicks, I notice I have to continuously pass in the Subcontroller and Username when creating new windows, since I will need to access that information from within the new window. For example, if Bob logs in, the windows created are:

Main GUI (Login screen) —> LoggedIn (has a greeting and a Create Routine Button, let’s say Bob presses on Create Routine) —> CreateRoutine GUI (simply a window with a text area for a routine name, and an OK button to create a routine with that name and assign that routine to Bob’s user).

The username information originated from the main GUI (from the Username field), which is then passed into LoggedIn (which is needed to write the user’s name in the greeting message label).

My Subcontroller has a createRoutine(String routineName, String userName) method which will be given the routine name, as well as who created the routine, create this routine, then assign this routine to the user who created it.

Therefor, from within CreateRoutine GUI, I call this createRoutine() method, and must give it the routineName, and the userName.

However, this method is from the subcontroller, and therefore I must pass the subcontroller to the instance of the CreateRoutine GUI. Additionally, I must pass in the user’s name (since it will be required for the createRoutine() method.

I notice that the deeper and deeper I progress (as in, the more and more sequential windows that the user will create), I am always having to pass in certain information to the window initializations that will be needed. Is there any way around this? Is this how it’s supposed to be? I feel like my program gets very messy like this. I guess to simplify the question - is it proper for me to continuously have to pass in my subcontroller or user’s name to newly created windows since I will need it? Is there not a way for me to access it on the fly anywhere without passing it in?

Thanks guys.

Comment: This might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as this doesn't appear to be a specific programming question.

Comment: a long story though, providing code sample will be much easier to read

Comment: I doubt many people are going to bother reading this, myself included.

Comment: Summary: As I create more and more GUIs, I find that I need to continuously pass information from GUI 1 to GUI 2 via the constructor of GUI 2 in order to be able to use that information from within GUI 2. As I go deeper into GUI 15 (for example), I need to continuously pass said information through all the GUI consturctors. Is this the proper way to do so in order to access information from GUI 1 from within GUI 15?

Comment: @tnw when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: One good way of creating a complex GUI is to use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  As you've discovered, there's certain information that the entire GUI needs to function properly.  You create a GUI model that contains this information, and pass an instance of the GUI model to all of the GUI view classes and GUI controller classes that need to read and modify, respectively, the information.